# *Lest* I forget

Tags: word-usage, syntax

If I am going to meet someone soon, and want to make sure to discuss a certain topic with them then, does it make sense to quickly text them

*Lest I forget: Can you explain to me ....?*

My question is not about the appropriateness/effectiveness of this, but about the meaning and syntax of *lest*.

Googling this only brings up about war remembrance

Comment: Just look up *lest* in a dictionary and all things should be clear.

Answer (score 2):

I'm a native American English speaker and I just used the conjunction "lest" twice last night in my five-page English paper for an American Literature class I'm taking, and I also said it today in class to two students whom I was talking to (about three times in 15 seconds as I was trying to get my point across).

Here are the quotations from my paper:

> "This quotation is still relevant today because it epitomizes
>   self-reliance and individualism as a whole—the concept that we should
>   do our best not to fall into the trap of relying on others *lest we
>   succumb* to conformity, thereby losing our individuality."
>
> "It is essentially a wake-up call to us that we must think for
>   ourselves *lest we become* like the sot in Emerson’s parable."

The situation today in class wherein I used "lest" is as follows:

> "I made sure not to use the neuter 'he' in my paper again even
>   though Emerson uses it throughout 'Self-Reliance' because I know how
>   Sister Cynthia thinks it's sexist language.  Since I'm attending a
>   college that is 93% female, I figure that I should be as pro-feminist
>   as possible *lest I be chased off* campus with pitchforks."

The two students responded jokingly that they don't have pitchforks in the dorms, so they won't chase me off campus with pitchforks, but maybe with something else.  So based upon my use of "lest" and still remembering the day in second grade when we learned the word "lest" as our teacher wrote it on the chalkboard in a sentence, I think it is still a very common word albeit very formal.  Yes, you can text "lest I forget"; it's a lot faster and simpler than typing out "in case I forget".  We're always trying to save time in text-speak anyway, right?

> **NOTE:** *Remember that if you use the word "lest", it is followed by the present subjunctive conjugation of the verb in English.*

I hope that might have helped you out.  Take care and good luck.

***P.S.*** Here is another excerpt from a paper that I just wrote last night.  In my envoi, I state:

> "The famous philosopher Baltasar Gracián once said, “All that really
>   belongs to us is time; even he who has nothing else has that.”  It is
>   by this credo that Le Ly Hayslip has lived her life and it is by this
>   credo that we should live ours *lest time itself pass us by* into
>   oblivion like a wraith of smoke from the extinguished fire of our
>   minds."

Comment: well done for using it, and I up-voted you for that. In English English I've only heard it used ceremoniously or for comedy effect such as inflecting irony.

Comment: Yes, [Oxford](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/lest)  marks it as formal.

Answer (score 0):

*Googling this only brings up about war remembrance*

Thats because its an archaic word only really used in historical works and in ceremonial situations. It has [Old English roots](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/lest) and is little modified since then other than in spelling. Its used in shakespeare [sonnet #72](http://www.shakespeare-online.com/sonnets/72.html)

A good modern alternative might be "**in case** I forget", I have never used "lest" other than when reading old passages aloud or looking at War Memorials.

Comment: But *lest* does not mean *in case I forget* but *so that I don't forget*. And *[lest](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/lest)* is not archaic, it's formal.